# how to get data from specified lines only from txt file using php

Tags: php

I have a txt file which contains data pertaining to hourly wind parameters for a particular date see this link for file

http://dropcanvas.com/04o06

In this the first hour data, that is 00:00:00 hrs is from line no. 3 to 30. I want date and time from 3rd line, stability class value in parenthesis from 5th line and wind speed and direction from 5th and 6th column of 12th line. I know how to get data and I coded in this way.

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("201017.dat", "r");
$line_no=0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $line_no++;
   if($line_no==3 ){
       $data=explode("\t",$line);
       $date=$data[0];
       $time=date('H:i:s',strtotime($data[1]));
       }

     if ($line_no==5 )   {

        preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $line, $match);

        $stability= $match[0];
        }
        if ($line_no==12 )   {

        $data=explode("\t",$line);

        $speed= $data[4];
        $dir= $data[5];
        }



}
$values[]="('$date', '$time',$dir,$speed,'$stability')";
```

Now the next hour data I need to push into array is from line no. 31,33 and 40. I can use if....else if for the entire 24 blocks of data which I feel is a cumbersome procedure. Is there a way to simplify this given the the line numbers are in arithmetic progression with a common difference of 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = file('201017.dat'); // read the whole file into array
/* NOTE! The whole file will be loaded into RAM,
so take into account ram restrictions for big files.
In this case 90kb is very small size */

$n = count($arr);

/* start with 2, because array indexes start with 0,
so the 3rd line will have index 2.
On the next interation $i will be 30 (that is 31th line,
$i+2 will be 33th line, $i+9 will be 40th line, etc.) */

for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i += 28)  
{
  $data=explode("\t", $arr[$i]);
  $date=$data[0];
  $time=date('H:i:s',strtotime($data[1]));

  preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $arr[$i+2], $match); // i+2 gives 5th line
  $stability= $match[0];
  $data=explode("\t", $arr[$i+9]);
  $speed = $data[4];
  $dir = $data[5];
  $values[]="('$date', '$time',$dir,$speed,'$stability')";
} 

var_dump($values); 
/*
 Shows:
   [0]=>
   string(52) "('10/20/2017', '00:00:00',    220.00,      1.39,'D')"
   [1]=>
   string(52) "('10/20/2017', '01:00:00',    215.00,      0.15,'E')"
   [2]=>
   string(52) "('10/20/2017', '02:00:00',    199.00,      0.95,'D')"
   [3]=>
   string(52) "('10/20/2017', '03:00:00',    203.00,      1.03,'D')" 
   ..... etc.
 */
```